# Add a label to a section of tableView when it's empty

Tags: swift, uitableview

Almost the same question many times has been asked here, but my question is a bit different, for example here, a users shows a really good way to handing an empty tableview with a label

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if self.numberOfRow == 0{
    var emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
    emptyLabel.text = "No Data"
    emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyLabel
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    return 0
} else {
    return self.numberOfRow
    }
}
```

It works fine when there is a section, but my problem is, I have two section that users can move cells between them and I want, when one of them become empty, a label appear in the section to say it's empty. 
Could anyone modify this way to do that? also it should reload data to show this label, is it right?

Many thanks

Comment: The code you posted is not a good way to show a label when there are no rows.

Comment: I just want to show it as an example, do you know any good way to show a label with a section is empty? I mean label must be shown in the section, not in the entire tableview

Comment: But it's a bad example for any use case. `numberOfRowsInSection` is called over and over. No need to keep creating and displaying the label over and over too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to show a regular cell in the section if there are no other rows in the section.

Here's some rough pseudocode:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionData = data[section]
    return sectionData.isEmpty ? 1 : sectionData.count
}

tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let sectionData = data[section]
    if sectionData.isEmpty {
        // create plain cell
        cell.textLabel.text = "Nothing to see here"

        return cell
    } else {
        // create and return your normal data cell from the data for the index path
    }
}
```

Another option is to show a section header or footer for any section that has no rows.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to show any cell when it's empty, I tried this way, but in my case, it make cause many other problems.

Comment: You need to show something in the section since that is your requirement. Fix whatever the other problems are. You of course need to check `if sectionData.isEmpty` in all of the data source and delegate methods to prevent the user from editing or moving those dummy rows. It's not too hard as long as you cover all of the methods.

Comment: I added another option to my answer.